# Get parent div using href

Tags: javascript, dom

Is is possible to find the parent div using just the href?

I basically have the following function:

```
var hrefs = [];
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("area"), function (value, index, array) {
    hrefs.push(value.getAttribute("href"));
});

for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    console.log(hrefs[i]);
    }
```

which finds all hrefs that belong to a html area. I am trying to find the parent element of these hrefs so that I can append a new div to that parents element. If this is not possible, what attribute would I need to be able to located the parent div of that attribute.

Comment: No, `href` is just a string. Why are you not just iterating over the areas directly?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying 'getting elements based on hrefs'?

Comment: Once you get the proper values (i.e DOM nodes), use `.parentNode`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode. *"what attribute would I need to be able to located the parent div of that attribute."* Attributes don't have parents. Attributes belong to a node and that node can have a parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want something like this?:

```
var hrefs = document.querySelectorAll("area");

for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++) {
    console.log(hrefs[i].getAttribute('href'));
    console.log(hrefs[i].parentNode);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First create an object with all those elements:

```
var hrefs = {};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("area[href]"), function (element) {
    hrefs[ element.getAttribute("href") ] = element;
});
```

Then you can get to their parent by using `.parentNode`:

```
for ( var i in hrefs ) {
    console.log( i, hrefs[i].parentNode );
}
```

---

So, if you want to later add an element to the parent of `http://www.google.com`, you could do this:

```
hrefs['http://www.google.com'].parentNode.appendChild( element );
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see why you wouldn't just:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("area"), function(area) {
    area.parentNode.appendChild(
        document.createElement("div")
    );
});
```

Comment: You should note that the solution requires ES5 and HTML5 support as well as allowing host objects to be treated as native objects. IE 8 at least fails on 2 out of 3 of those.

Comment: @RobG In IE8 `.call` only doesn't work for host objects when the host object is a receiver, it does work with host object as an argument. It also doesn't technically require ES5 - if someone has defined `Array#forEach` even with the most basic semantics it works :P.

Answer (score 0):

The strategy is to get all the area elements, then match on their href value. The following returns the first matching area element:

```
function getAreaByHref(href) {
  var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area');
  for (var i = 0, iLen=areas.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    if (areas[i].href == href) {
      return areas[i].parentNode;
    }
  }
}
```

If you think there will be more than one, have the function build an array of matched elements and return that.

Answer (score -2):

If you use jQuery, there is a .parent() method that you can use to accomplish this.

Comment: Assuming the OP has DOM elements, then they could just use `.parentNode`. No need for jQuery.